# cannot set type primitive.ObjectID to ObjectID

Tags: mongodb, go

Getting this error while binding mongodb document to GO Struct using docstore collection iterator.

Database: Azure CosmosDB mongoDb API
Go Driver: Docstore

Code details:

**Cosmos DB Constructors Code**

```
    client, err := c.newClient(ctx, true)
    if err != nil {
        log.Error("error connecting to mongodb cluster", zap.Error(err))
        return nil, err
    }

    database := client.Database(c.dbName)
    collection := database.Collection(c.collName)

    return mongodocstore.OpenCollection(collection, "", nil)
```

**Go struct for mapping with Mongo Db document**

```
type utterance struct {
    ID               primitive.ObjectID `docstore:"_id,omitempty"`
    User             string             `docstore:"user,omitempty"`
    Locale           string             `docstore:"Locale,omitempty"`
    Text             string             `docstore:"Text,omitempty"`
    Source           string             `docstore:"Source,omitempty"`
    Timestamp        time.Time          `docstore:"Timestamp,omitempty"`
    DocstoreRevision interface{}
}
```

**MondoDb Document**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60d5e18539864e948a8851a6"),
    "User" : "auth0|6049b5ef5d79540071db6a0a",
    "Locale" : "en_US",
    "Text" : "Hi",
    "Source" : "UTTERANCE_SOURCE_USER",
    "Timestamp" : {
        "$date" : 1624629637002
    },
    "DocstoreRevision" : "bf3b35d8-54ed-4a23-a08f-7d41b5c34085"
}
```

**Method to call the docstore collection and iterate**

```
i := s.collection.Query().Get(ctx)
    defer i.Stop()

    var results []*services.Utterance

    for {
        fmt.Println("for every document: ")
        //var native utterance
        doc := &utterance{}
        err := i.Next(ctx, doc) //error at this line
        if err == io.EOF {
            break
        } else if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(“getting to this err block“)
            return nil, err
        }

        u := doc.ToProto()
        results = append(results, u)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the `ID` to a pointer type:

```golang
type utterance struct {
    ID               *primitive.ObjectID `docstore:"_id,omitempty"`
    User             string             `docstore:"user,omitempty"`
    Locale           string             `docstore:"Locale,omitempty"`
    Text             string             `docstore:"Text,omitempty"`
    Source           string             `docstore:"Source,omitempty"`
    Timestamp        time.Time          `docstore:"Timestamp,omitempty"`
    DocstoreRevision interface{}
}
```

Probably when you create the struct to be decoded the `primitive.ObjectID` is being initialized and the driver don't know to decode it.

And be careful. The `docstore` is a generic Document driver. It is not specific for MongoDB. So it probably don't work well with MongoDB specific types.

---

Reading the driver for `mongodb` https://pkg.go.dev/gocloud.dev/docstore/mongodocstore

There is a way to set what is stored in the `_id` field. I understand `docstore` don't know how to decode `ObjectID` from MongoDB.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Tried with *primitive.ObjectID, but getting the same error as before.

Comment: So it is possible that `docstore` can't decode the `ObjectID`, if you remove does it work? And if you change it to string?

Comment: Yep https://pkg.go.dev/gocloud.dev/docstore/mongodocstore, it doesn't work but it has workarounds. If you check the link there is a way to change what is saved in the _id field

Comment: If i remove, it gives an error saying 'no field matching “_id”'. and if i change it to string error is 'cannot set type string to ObjectID'

Comment: From link pkg.go.dev/gocloud.dev/docstore/mongodocstore, i understood the reference of '_id' while opening the collection 'mongodocstore.OpenCollection(collection, "", nil)'. But i did not get the mapping with mongodb document struct

Comment: Did you remove the doc from database and inserted it again? Because, if I understood right, it should use another field in the _id. You cloud use the `User`field.

Comment: Yes. I tried adding a new document. Option 1: passing objectID in payload as u.ID = primitive.NewObjectID() Option 2:auto generated with ObjectId(). Both fails while reading the document.

Comment: First of all, Why i cannot skip ID from the Go struct? If i remove it, error is 'no field matching \"_id\'

Comment: I think is the driver... Docstore doesn't know how to do that... with the `mongodb-driver` I did that with no problem at all.

Comment: Thank you @lucas for quick help that day. I have also preferred using mongodb-driver over of Docstore. It's working now.